# XMLRPC in java to invoke a method with no arguments?

Tags: java

I have a Remote method in a server with no arguments. I 'am not able to invoke it from my java client. But i'm able to invoke a method with arguments.

```
**XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
config.setServerURL(new URL("http://localhost:8000"));
client.setConfig(config);
Object[] params = new Object[]{null};
Object result = client.execute("hello",params);
System.out.println(result);**
```

Comment: Did you get any exceptions or error message?

Comment: I don't find any XmlRpcClient methods to invoke a remote method which has no arguments. 
Above code gave me
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.xmlrpc.common.XmlRpcExtensionException: Null values aren't supported, if isEnabledForExtensions()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
Object[] params = new Object[]{null};
```

(a single-element array containing `null`) try

```
Object[] params = new Object[0];
```

(an empty array).

Comment: Jus additional info...
Object result = client.execute("hello",new ArrayList());
also worked...

Answer (score 2):

Using `new Object[] {null}` you are assuming there is at least one argument (null).
You just need to create an empty array:

```
new Object[0];
```